# Problem to load from ID of a resource file in Delphi

Tags: delphi

When I use the method `LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'PNGImage0')` it works, but when I use `LoadFromResourceID(Hinstance, 0)` don't. It returns me an exception EResNotFound with message 'Resource 0 not found'.

I'd like to know what's the problem?

### Edit

My RC File:

```
PNGImage0 RCDATA "Image0.png"
PNGImage1 RCDATA "Image1.png"
PNGImage2 RCDATA "Image2.png"
PNGImage3 RCDATA "Image3.png"
PNGImage4 RCDATA "Image4.png"
PNGImage5 RCDATA "Image5.png"
PNGImage6 RCDATA "Image6.png"
```

Comment: looks like the ID zero does not exist. Can you append your RC file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK a resource is identified **either** by name **or** by ID. You probably have an resource script (*.rc) that identifies the image by name like

```
PNGImage0 RCDATA "FileName.png"
```

where PNGImage0 is **not** defined as a number.

To define PNGImage0 as a number, just have

```
const
  PNGImage0 = 1;
```

in a unit (say YourResDefines.pas) and put `#include "YourResDefines.pas"` at the top of the *.rc file. Then you have to use `LoadFromResourceID(HInstance, PNGImage0)` without the single quotes.

Comment: How can I define PNGImage0 as a number?

Comment: @PA: Correct but I'd prefer named constants instead of magic numbers.

Comment: @PA not works to me. I've tried to rename PNGImage0, PNGImage1, etc to 0, 1, etc but BRCC32 returns to me the following: "Error MyRCFile.rc 1 3: Not a positive short integer"

Comment: @Ulrich I made what you suggested and the error is the same I told to @PA

Comment: @Ulrich Now it's working. Thank you very much. You help me to save a lot of LOC.